# Are "travel trailers"/"mobile homes" brakeable from the inside?

Tags: security, trailer, rv, motorhome

I have this feeling that, if I were to move into one of those things which I don't know what to call them, which look like a very small house and has wheels and a little thing to attach to a car, somebody could just drive there with their car, hook it up and drive away with me and my home.

Do they have like a switch inside of the living area where you can securely "lock" the wheels so that they won't go anywhere? And this cannot be "unsecured" from the outside? Please tell me this is the case. It would make me feel better for those who live in one as well.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the UK caravans have a parking brake on the wheels, but it is often not used when parking on level ground because corrosion caused by rain etc can lock the brakes "on" and the van can't be moved at all until it is freed.

Caravans have "legs" at each corner which are wound down to support the caravan when it is not being towed. Otherwise, being inside the caravan is not very pleasant because whenever you move about, the caravan moves on its suspension.

You can also get wheel locks, similar to the locks for cars or bikes, and towing hitch locks which prevent the caravan from being towed if they are not removed.

If you were inside the caravan when thieves attempted to steal it by towing it away, you would almost certainly be aware something was going on before they had driven away with you still inside.

Finally, trying to tow away a stolen van without checking whether everything inside is properly stowed away would be a bad idea, unless the thieves don't mind things being thrown around and broken inside the van as they drive, liquids being spilled, etc.